# Python 3, remove duplicate of tuples in other lists of lists

Tags: python-3.x

Hi im looking for a way to remove duplicate of tuples from one list when compared to tuples in others different lists and/or lists of lists of tuples.

Example :

```
possible_cell = [(7,7),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
wrong_path = [(1,1),(1,2),[(3,3)]]
current_path = [(4,4),[(5,5)]]
this_path = [(6,6)]
```

wanted :

```
new_possible_cell = [2-tuple for 2-tuple in possible_cell if 2-tuple not in wrong_path and 2-tuple not in current_path etc....]
```

expected return :

new_possible_cell = [(7,7)]

Answer (score 2):

You're close, just flatten the list first.

```
possible_cell = [(7,7),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
wrong_path = [(1,1),(1,2),[(3,3)]]
current_path = [(4,4),[(5,5)]]
this_path = [(6,6)]

def flatten(L):
    for x in L:
        if type(x) == list:
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x

new_possible_cell = [x for x in possible_cell if x not in flatten(wrong_path+current_path+this_path)]

print(new_possible_cell)
```

output:

```
[(7, 7)]
```

If your lists are large, use `set(flatten(...))` for better speed.